# How to implement Qt qmake tool dry run mode

Tags: qt, qmake

I just want to use `qmake` as `pro`-files parser for extracting project variables (like `SOURCES`), nothing more. I don't need to generate makefiles.

In other similar tools `"dry run"` mode usually presents. I.e. "just taste this thing, but do nothing with it".
Unfortunately `qmake` don't have such mode, but can i emulate it with some, probably ugly||hacky way?

Now i'm trying to remove all "generation"-code from qmake source, but it is hard and long task. And i'm like simple decisions :)

Comment: Interesting question, so I upvoted it, but can you please mention an actual use case for it? What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need qmake for such a task?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Thanks for up. My purpose is to extract HEADERS and SOURCES variables from complicated qmake project. I'll need them to be used in my requirements management tool to link the source code with requirement ids'. So i need the complete list of project sources and header.

Comment: @Axilles: what is this requirement management tool? Cannot you use a script for this simple task? Why don't you use Enterprise Architect or similar tools for the job, by the way?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Do you mean to write a script for parsing `pro`-files? Those ones are too complicated :( I'm trying to write my own parser, but i'm stuck on recursive subprojects/includes parsing...
And about my req tool purpose: 1) it simplify manager work: GUI is very simple 2) it can generate various reports and documentation using LyX/LaTeX, in various styles and 3) it does not using "heavy" databases like Oracle, just plain XML. I.e. easy to install and maintain to admin.

Comment: @LaszloPapp You say that as thought it was a bad thing :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to give the `-E` option to qmake. It will dump the contents of the project variables and continue without generating the makefile.

It is equivalent to the code snippet given in previous edition of this post, but dumps all of the variables and requires no changes to qmake :)

Comment: Thanks, but 1) it is marked as deprecated and 2) it enable debug mode, but i'm need a silent one. However, it's better than qmake hacking :)

Comment: However, this line looks like my salvation: `Option::mkfile::do_preprocess = true;`
If i will not get any other answer, i will you use your way. Thanks again :)

Comment: '-E' enables do_preprocess. I don't see where it's "deprecated". It's simply not documented, that's all.

Comment: [I see this in qmake sources](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/8dc37368441d13f41f029b4191ce734a9758d2c8:qmake/option.cpp#L312)